# Circle of squares

Tags: java, math

Can you arrange numbers 1 to 16 in a circle such that the sum of adjacent two numbers is a perfect square? If yes, how and if not, why not?
Can you write a program to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: if this is homework it should be tagged as such, also the question needs better explanation, for example what does adjacent mean.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask programming questions -- if you show code you've tried, describe the error you're getting or where specifically you're stuck, we might be able to help.

Comment: "techbeast" - interesting handle.

Answer (score 8):

Hint for you. Using this set of numbers, there is only one possible sum which includes 16 that makes a perfect square (16+9 = 25), so the answer is no.

Comment: Errm.... 1+3, 4+5, 4+12, 1+8....

Comment: Yeah, I know - I forgot the key point about including 16...

Comment: I think what James meant was that since it's a circle of numbers, any number in the circle will have to make a perfect square with the number to the left AND to the right of it. Effectively, each number will be used twice in addition. But 16 only has one possible combination to make a perfect square, and that's (16+9). Therefore, there's no possible combination that completes the circle. (Even Forrest's answer above is incorrect in this respect).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it now. Because it's a circle, sixteen would be adjacent to two numbers, and therefore it would have to be included in two sums. And you've pointed out that it can only be in one sum, so therefore the answer is no. Ah-ha.

Comment: But let's claim I was being deliberately obscure with the hint so I wouldn't take all the fun out of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9, 16]

And yes, I can write a program to solve it.

EDIT: Just realised this isn't a circle ... this is the only linear solution, so my answer is:

No, not possible.

Comment: A circle has no beginning and no end. Starting this sequence at, say, the 12, and you run into 16 + 1 = 17.

Comment: Forrest, this arrangement is not a circle, never the less if we were to write a program for this what would be the algorithm (apart from hit and trial

Comment: Starting with any of the numbers (I started with 1), enumerate all the possibilities for the next number (range from 1 to 16 filtered with whether it makes a perfect square if summed with the last element), and recursively try each of these.

Comment: but this is close. I'm giving it +1

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO
If you look backward from 16->1, 16 need 2 adjacent number satisfied that the sum is perfect square. But we can only find 16+9=25, and no more. (because the next one is 16 or 36, which are both impossible).
But, if the problem change to a **linear instead of circle**, then there will be a solution：
8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9, 16
And this is the only possible solution.

Here I attached my code to solve the linear version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PerfectSquareLinear {
    public static final int MAX_NUMBER = 16;
    public static int[] square = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new PerfectSquareLinear().go();
    }

    public boolean sumIsPerfectSquare(int a, int b) {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(square, a + b) < 0 ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param l
     *            current result array
     * @param p
     *            position to fill in
     * @param pool
     *            available numbers
     */
    public void fill(int[] l, int p, int[] pool) {

        if (p > MAX_NUMBER - 1) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++) {
                if (pool[i] > 0) {
                    l[p] = pool[i];
                    if (p == 0 || sumIsPerfectSquare(l[p], l[p - 1])) {
                        pool[i] = -1;
                        fill(l, p + 1, pool);
                        pool[i] = i + 1;
                    } else {
                        // System.out.println("dead end: " +
                        // Arrays.toString(l));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        // the result array for compute the permutation
        int[] list = new int[MAX_NUMBER];
        // the pool array to store the available number
        int[] pool = new int[MAX_NUMBER];
        // initial pool array
        for (int n = 1; n <= MAX_NUMBER; n++) {
            pool[n - 1] = n;
        }
        fill(list, 0, pool);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be wrong, but I can't seem to find possible cycles with this code:

```
/**
 * @author BjørnS
 * @created 30. aug. 2010
 */
public class PerfectSquares {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> options = Lists.newArrayList();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
            options.add(i);
        }

        List<Integer> start = start(options);

        if (start == null) {
            System.out.println("Unsolvable unless this code is wrong.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("My answer is: " + start);
        }

    }

    private static List<Integer> start(List<Integer> options) {

        for (Integer i : options) {

            List<Integer> li = Lists.newArrayList(options);
            li.remove(i);

            List<Integer> ws = Lists.newArrayList(i);

            List<Integer> answer = findAnswer(ws, li);
            if (answer != null) {
                return answer;
            }
            ws = null;
            li = null;
        }

        return null;

    }

    private static List<Integer> findAnswer(List<Integer> workingSet, List<Integer> options) {

        Integer last = workingSet.get(workingSet.size() - 1);

        if (options.size() == 1) {

            Integer first = workingSet.get(0);

            Integer option = options.get(0);

            if (isPerfectSquare(first, option) && isPerfectSquare(last, option)) {
                workingSet.add(option);
                System.out.println("I think it is:" + workingSet);
                return workingSet;
            }
            return null;
        }

        for (Integer i : options) {

            if (isPerfectSquare(last, i)) {

                List<Integer> li = Lists.newArrayList(options);
                li.remove(i);

                List<Integer> ws = Lists.newArrayList(workingSet);
                ws.add(i);

                System.out.println("trying " + ws);

                List<Integer> answer = findAnswer(ws, li);
                if (answer != null) {
                    System.out.println("Potential answer:" + answer);
                    return ws;
                }

                li = null;
                ws = null;

            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isPerfectSquare(Integer a, Integer b) {

        return Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(a + b)), 2) == (a + b);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the graph with vertices 1, 2, ..., 16, and edges (a, b) if a + b is square, then the problem is the equivalent to finding a hamiltonian path on this graph.

Finding hamiltonian paths is in general NP, which suggests you're not going to do better than a search.